# Blend and equally distant objects

Tags: adobe-illustrator

How can I blend two objects and keep equal distance between them, not from their centres but from their whole figure (so the space between the objects is always the same)?

e.g. in this blending, the distance is equal between centres. I am looking for a bending that leaves same space between objects.

[image: wrong result where distance is equal between centres]

**Note**: I would like to avoid the use of brushes, that can create some inconsistencies in the objects I place.

Comment: I think the method explained in your suggestion (via art brushes) creates some undesired distortion. There should exist another way in Illustrator